# Apple Push Notification error setting private key

Tags: ios, ssl, apple-push-notifications

I have been fighting to get the push notification certificates setup correctly for my app.  The app is already in the store, so I can't just 'start over' generating files as has been the solution for others having this problem!

I have used this article as an example to create the certificates: http://www.raywenderlich.com/32960/apple-push-notification-services-in-ios-6-tutorial-part-1#comments.  When I get to the point of testing what I have generated I get:

> openssl s_client -connect gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195 -cert
>   PushTestCert.pem -key PushTestKey.pem
>   Enter pass phrase for
>   PushTestKey.pem:
>   error setting private key
>   4368:error:0B080074:x509
>   certificate routines:X509_check_private_key:key values
>   mismatch:/SourceCache/OpenSSL098/OpenSSL098-35.1/src/crypto/x509/x509_cmp.c:406:

The example shows the app in the Keys section of Keychain Access.  My app is there, but under the private key it has a certificate (my iPhone Developer certificate).  Do I need to export both items into my p12, or just the private key?

I've tried both downloading the aps_development.cer and turning it into a pem and creating the cert pem from Keychain Access, and not having success in either case.

Other posts have suggested that the app p12 is wrong, but how can I see what the private key is and why there is a mismatch???

Answer (score 2):

You should provide your apns certificate as separated cert/key pem files. and you need to remove the password from your key pem.

**Separate pem files from p12**

```
openssl pkcs12 -clcerts -nokeys -out cert.pem -in cert.p12

openssl pkcs12 -nocerts -out key.pem -in key.p12
```

**Remove password from pem file**

```
openssl rsa -in key.pem -out key-noenc.pem
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but there is no change in the error I am receiving.  I have edited the post to provide more info as to what I am doing.

Answer (score 1):

My problem was that I was creating a separate Certificate for the Push Notification.  Once I used the original CSR for the app everything worked fine.

My bad!